# Stop fadeIn and fadeOut repeating multiple times(event is triggered by scrolling, not hovering)

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

All other solutions had the FadeIn/FadeOut event triggered by mouse hover.
my event is triggered whenever we scroll.

example: [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LFqMJ/)

All other solutions on stackoverflow use `.stop()` or `.stop(true,true)`, it works for hover triggered events. But i cant use that for scroll triggered event as it eliminates the fading effect almost completely. This is because "hover" triggers the event only once, but "scrolling" triggers the same event many times.

[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LFqMJ/1/) example shows that the fade effect is gone if i use `.stop(true,true)`.

Is there any solution such that the fadeIn/fadeOut shoudnt repeat while still keeping the fading effect.

Thank you.

Comment: something like it shoudnt stop the animation. just eliminate repeating events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the :animated selector to only run the fade animation when still, ensuring the animation isn't interrupted or queued. See below

Edit: fix for interrupt

```
$(function () {
    $("#id_home").hide();
    var offset_top = 100;
    var check_div = function (verify) {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (!$("#id_home:animated").length || verify) {
            if (scroll_top > offset_top) {
                $("#id_home").fadeIn(1300, function () {
                    if (!verify) check_div(true);
                });
                //$("#id_home").fadeIn(1000);
            } else {
                $("#id_home").fadeOut(1300, function () {
                    if (!verify) check_div(true);
                });
                //$("#id_home").fadeOut(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    // run our function on load
    check_div(false);

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        check_div();
    });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LFqMJ/4/

Comment: Thank you. 
Ignore the edit i made. I guess it was a bug in my browser. It is working perfectly fine now.